# C++ regex, unknown escape sequence '\.' warning

Tags: c++, regex

First time I tried using regular expressions in C++, and I'm a little confused about escape sequences. I'm simply trying to match a dot at the beginning of a string. For that I'm using the expression: "^\\\.", which works, but my compiler (g++) generates a warning:

```
warning: unknown escape sequence '\.'
        regex self_regex("^\\\.");
                             ^~
```

If I'm using e.g "^\\.", it does not generate a warning, but that regex does not match what I intend to do.

I also don't understand why I have to use three backslashes, shouldn't two be sufficient, in "\." the first backslash escapes the second one, so that I actually search for ., but it doesn't work. Can someone please clarify this for me?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main(void){
    DIR *dir;
    string path = "/Users/-----------/Documents/Bibliothek/MachineLearning/DeepLearning/ConvolutionalNeuralNetworks/CS231n 2016/Assignments/assignment3/assignment3/cs231n";
    regex self_regex("^\\\.+");
    struct dirent *ent;
    dir = opendir(path.c_str());
    if ((dir = opendir(path.c_str())) != NULL){
        while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL){
            if (regex_search(string(ent->d_name),self_regex)){
                cout << "matches regex" << ent->d_name << endl;
            }
            else{
                cout << "does not match regex " << ent->d_name << endl;
            }
        }
        closedir(dir);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
matches regex.
matches regex..
matches regex.DS_Store
matches regex.gitignore
does not match regex __init__.py
does not match regex __init__.pyc
does not match regex build
does not match regex captioning_solver.py
does not match regex captioning_solver.pyc
does not match regex classifiers
does not match regex coco_utils.py
does not match regex coco_utils.pyc
does not match regex data_utils.py
does not match regex datasets
does not match regex fast_layers.py
does not match regex fast_layers.pyc
does not match regex gradient_check.py
does not match regex gradient_check.pyc
does not match regex im2col.py
does not match regex im2col.pyc
does not match regex im2col_cython.c
does not match regex im2col_cython.pyx
does not match regex im2col_cython.so
does not match regex image_utils.py
does not match regex image_utils.pyc
does not match regex layer_utils.py
does not match regex layers.py
does not match regex layers.pyc
does not match regex optim.py
does not match regex optim.pyc
does not match regex rnn_layers.py
does not match regex rnn_layers.pyc
does not match regex setup.py
```

Comment: Please post the whole chunk of relevant code, the input string, and expected behavior. BTW, checking if a string starts with a dot does not require a regex.

Comment: `\\\.` becomes `\.` because the first backslash escapes the second one and the third one escapes the dot

Comment: You can just use `regex self_regex("^\\.+");` or even `regex self_regex("^\\.");`. Or best a raw string literal: `regex self_regex(R"(^\.)");`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oh you're right it works. I must have mixed something up, I'm relatively certain that I actually tried two backslashes, maybe in a slightly different context, and then as a result that regex matched everything, but when I now use two backslashes it works. Thanks.

Comment: Some point snipers already posted answers, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you write in your code a string literal:

```
"^\\\."
```

your compiler will parse it according to the C++ rules to generate the string that will be used in your executable.  For example if `\n` would be encountered the string in your executable would contain a newline instead.  The `"\\"` is transformed into `"\"`, but your compiler doesn't know how to handle `"\."` because there is [no such escape sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) defined in C++.

> Escape sequences in which the character following the backslash is
>   not listed (...) are conditionally-supported, with
>   implementation-defined semantics.

So the string you're looking for is with only two slashes:

```
"^\\."
```

which will be transformed by the compiler into:

```
"^\."
```

And this is the [regex you're looking for](https://regex101.com/r/xJ4wB7/1) !

Remark: GCC for example will transform an unknown escape sequence `"\."` into `"."`, so that 2 or 3 bakslashes will in reality produce the same result.

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/kbb1wq)

Comment: Or use a C++11 raw string (which is the only reasonable way to use regexes) to remove the need for all string level backslash escapes, so only regex escapes are needed: `R"(^\.)"`

Comment: @ShadowRanger Excellent suggestion !

Answer (score 6):

The compiler generates a warning because not every escape sequence has a meaning in C++.
The list of valid escape sequences can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape).

However, regex expects you to escape '.' in order to literally match a '.' character instead of anything. To escape '.' in a regex pattern, you must add a single '\' character before it. But since a single '\' means an escape in c++, you need to put two backslashes: "\\". Therefore, the correct pattern is "^\\.".